# How can I put a timer on the user input?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a bomb defusal minigame where you are given 4 random colors and you need to cut the right wires to win. The problem I'm having now is figuring out how to get it so there is a timer on each part where there needs to be an input from the player picking which color to cut, and then if the timer runs out the player fails.

I feel like I'm using setTimeout wrong, I can't figure out how to get it to work in the way I want it.

```
const asdf = require('readline').createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
});

asdf.question('What will you cut?', wire => { //First part where you are given 4 colors
    setTimeout(asdf.question, 7000, console.log("asdf"))
    if (!allowedColors.includes(wire)) {
        console.log("You need to pick one of the 4 colors!");
        return;
    }
    console.log(`You cut ${wire}!`);
    asdf.close();
    ruleEnforcer(wire, fourRandomColors, f);

})
```

Comment: Are you trying to log "asdf" after 7 seconds? If so its `setTimeout(console.log("asdf"), 7000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things you have you will have to adjust:

1. You are calling `setTimeout` in the callback function of `question`, so the timer will be started when the user typed a color and pressed enter
2. The way you are using it, `setTimeout` will call the function `asdf.question` after 7000ms and passes `console.log("asdf")` as an argument to the function that is called. You should look at the [API definition of setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) again
3. `setTimeout` is asynchronous, so if you want to stop the game if the timer runs out, your whole game should be asynchronous as well

A very basic implementation of this process (without multiple questions or actually checking if the entered color is correct) might look like this

```
const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
});

// start game and react to callback
startGame((win) => {
  readline.close()
  if(win) {
    console.log('you won')
  } else {
    console.log('you lost')
  }
})

function startGame(callback) {

  // set timer when game starts, if it runs out player loses -> call callback false
  let timer = setTimeout(() => {
    callback(false)
  }, 7000);

  readline.question('What will you cut?', wire => {
   // stop timer from running when player enters a color
   clearTimeout(timer);

   // wire is correct and player won the game -> call callback true
   callback(true)
  })
}
```